# how to use firebase ML kit for text recognition of non enlgish languages?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, text-recognition

It is stated in documentation that text recognition with ML kit supports over 100 languages and on my device it's working fine with English language only. How to change language of text recognition?

[image: We tried text extraction for english text successfully.]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just putting over another language and seeing if it is built in?

It says its still in beta but here is the link to check out

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/identify-languages

or try this

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/identification/ios

Comment: Thank you but i want text extraction and not identification of langugage

Answer (score 0):

[ML Kit Text Recognition SDK V2(Beta)](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2) has expanded the language set from latin-only to Chinese/Japanese/Devanagari/Korean as well:
Welcome to give it a try and feedback with your concerns. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you but I have tried this and this shows output on screen only. I mean that it does not give us string output and also it fails for many languages.

Comment: YOu can get the string output [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExampleObjC/ViewController.m#L714) ,  supported language set [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/languages)